# Creating a form that works for both creating and updating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a form where a user can input their favorite food. I want the form to work for both an existing favorite food, and a new favorite food.

I thought I could just switch what object the form is being created for like this:

```
<% if @user.favorite_food %>
  <%= form_for @user.favorite_food, :html => { class: :form } do |f| %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for :favorite_food, :url => :favorite_food, :html => { class: :form } do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

However I get an error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end`.

Comment: you are getting this error because you have not end the form .. put 2 <% end %> ,one before else and one after last end..but what do you mean by existing food in form..?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mayank comment your form should be like this

```
<% if @user.favorite_food %>

  <%= form_for @user.favorite_food, :html => { class: :form } do |f| %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for :favorite_food, :url => :favorite_food, :html => { class: :form } do |f| %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would better use a nested form for this and let the `UsersController` take care of the update:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { class: :form } do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :favourite_food do |food_form| %>
    <% # your favorite_food inputs go here %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In your `User` class you have to have `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
class User
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :favorite_food
  ...
end
```

In your `UserController` you need to make sure to permit the `favorite_food_attribures` on your strong parametes:

```
params.require(:person).permit(favorite_food_attribures: []) #do not delete the existing parameters that are already there.
```

You could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773978/rails-with-nested-form/22774381#22774381) for more info.

Hope this can help you.